# Find all indices/instances of all repeating patterns across columns and rows of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a simple pandas dataframe `df` as so:

```
     | name      | car   |
|----|-----------|-------|
| 0  | 'bob'     | 'b'   |
| 1  | 'bob'     | 'c'   |
| 2  | 'fox'     | 'b'   |
| 3  | 'fox'     | 'c'   |
| 4  | 'cox'     | 'b'   |
| 5  | 'cox'     | 'c'   |
| 6  | 'jo'      | 'b'   |
| 7  | 'jo'      | 'c'   |
| 8  | 'bob'     | 'b'   |
| 9  | 'bob'     | 'c'   |
| 10 | 'bob'     | 'b'   |
| 11 | 'bob'     | 'c'   |
| 12 | 'rob'     | 'b'   |
| 13 | 'rob'     | 'c'   |
```

I would like to find the row indices of a specific pattern that spans both columns. In my real application, the above dataframe has a few thousand rows and I have a few thousand dataframes so performance is not important. The pattern, say, that I am interested in is:

```
| 'bob'     | 'b'   |
| 'bob'     | 'c'   |
```

Hence, using the above example, my desired output would be:

```
out_idx = [0,1,8,9,10,11]
```

Typically of course, for one pattern, one would do something like `df.loc[(df.name == 'bob') & (df.car == 'b')]` but I am not sure how to do it when I am looking for a specific and multivariate pattern over multiple columns. I.e. I am looking for (and I am pretty the following is not correct): `df.loc[(df.name == 'bob') & (df.car == 'b') & (df.car == 'c')]`.

Help much appreciated. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) instead second and third conditions:

```
df1 = df[(df.name == 'bob') & df.car.isin(['b','c'])]
print (df1)
   name car
0   bob   b
1   bob   c
8   bob   b
9   bob   c
10  bob   b
11  bob   c
```

If need index values:

```
out_idx = df.index[(df.name == 'bob') & df.car.isin(['b','c'])]
```

Or:

```
out_idx = df[(df.name == 'bob') & df.car.isin(['b','c'])].index
```

Your solution is possible with `|` (bitwise OR) instead second `&` and also added one `()`:

```
df1 = df[(df.name == 'bob') & ((df.car == 'b') | (df.car == 'c'))]
```